# xslt outputs unwanted text - NOT default template

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I checked various posts about unwanted text but this doesn't seem to be that issue, so I hope the gurus on this list can help me. Apologies in advance if I have missed something very silly. I did try adding the 'empty' templates to tackle the default text issue.

This is my XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <EstimateDisplayRequest>
      <facXML>
        <faRecord>
         <recordCode>33</recordCode>
         <item>
            <itemMapCode>1</itemMapCode>
            <itemValue>A</itemValue>
         </item>
         <item>
            <itemMapCode>110</itemMapCode>
            <itemValue>*</itemValue>
         </item>
         <item>
            <itemMapCode>111</itemMapCode>
            <itemValue>C</itemValue>
         </item>
         <item>
            <itemMapCode>112</itemMapCode>
            <itemValue>20140528</itemValue>
         </item>
         <item>
            <itemMapCode>113</itemMapCode>
            <itemValue>154245</itemValue>
         </item>
         <item>
            <itemMapCode>114</itemMapCode>
            <itemValue>MCSTST</itemValue>
         </item>
         <item>
            <itemMapCode>115</itemMapCode>
            <itemValue>TRACYF</itemValue>
         </item>
         <item>
            <itemMapCode>116</itemMapCode>
            <itemValue>Tracy</itemValue>
         </item>
         <item>
            <itemMapCode>117</itemMapCode>
            <itemValue>Fry</itemValue>
         </item>
         </faRecord>
      </facXML>
   </EstimateDisplayRequest>
```

This is the xsl I am trying to use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="EstimateDisplayRequest">
        <MCSResponse>
            <EstimateDisplayResponse>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="EstimateDisplayResponse" />
            </EstimateDisplayResponse>
        </MCSResponse>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="faRecord/item[itemMapCode='1' and itemValue='A']" mode="EstimateDisplayResponse">
        <EstimateDisplayResponseDetailAudit>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*" mode="EstimateDisplayResponseDetailAudit" />
        </EstimateDisplayResponseDetailAudit>
    </xsl:template>  


    <xsl:template match="item[itemMapCode='110']" mode="EstimateDisplayResponseDetailAudit" >
        <FromStatus>
            <xsl:value-of select="./itemValue" />
        </FromStatus>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item[itemMapCode='111']" mode="EstimateDisplayResponseDetailAudit" >
        <ToStatus>
            <xsl:value-of select="./itemValue" />
        </ToStatus>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item[itemMapCode='112']" mode="EstimateDisplayResponseDetailAudit" >
        <ClientContactDateAudit>
            <xsl:value-of select="./itemValue" />
        </ClientContactDateAudit>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item[itemMapCode='113']" mode="EstimateDisplayResponseDetailAudit" >
        <Time>
            <xsl:value-of select="./itemValue" />
        </Time>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item[itemMapCode='114']" mode="EstimateDisplayResponseDetailAudit" >
        <UserId>
            <xsl:value-of select="./itemValue" />
        </UserId>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item[itemMapCode='115']" mode="EstimateDisplayResponseDetailAudit" >
        <PersonCode>
            <xsl:value-of select="./itemValue" />
        </PersonCode>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item[itemMapCode='116']" mode="EstimateDisplayResponseDetailAudit" >
        <PersonFirstName>
            <xsl:value-of select="./itemValue" />
        </PersonFirstName>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item[itemMapCode='117']" mode="EstimateDisplayResponseDetailAudit" >
        <PersonLastName>
            <xsl:value-of select="./itemValue" />
        </PersonLastName>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item[itemMapCode='118']" mode="EstimateDisplayResponseDetailAudit" >
        <Comment>
            <xsl:value-of select="./itemValue" />
        </Comment>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item[itemMapCode='119']" mode="EstimateDisplayResponseDetailAudit" >
        <AuditGAPStatus>
            <xsl:value-of select="./itemValue" />
        </AuditGAPStatus>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item[itemMapCode='120']" mode="EstimateDisplayResponseDetailAudit" >
        <AuditGAPExpiryDate>
            <xsl:value-of select="./itemValue" />
        </AuditGAPExpiryDate>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item[itemMapCode='121']" mode="EstimateDisplayResponseDetailAudit" >
        <AuditGAPEmailAddressUsed>
            <xsl:value-of select="./itemValue" />
        </AuditGAPEmailAddressUsed>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item[itemMapCode='122']" mode="EstimateDisplayResponseDetailAudit" >
        <AuditGAPComments>
            <xsl:value-of select="./itemValue" />
        </AuditGAPComments>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this is the output I get:

```
    <mcsresponse>
      <estimatedisplayresponse>
        33
        <estimatedisplayresponsedetailaudit>
            <fromstatus>*</fromstatus>
            <tostatus>C</tostatus>
            <clientcontactdateaudit>20140528</clientcontactdateaudit>
            <time>154245</time>
            <userid>MCSTST</userid>
            <personcode>TRACYF</personcode>
            <personfirstname>Tracy</personfirstname>
            <personlastname>Fry</personlastname>
        </estimatedisplayresponsedetailaudit>
        110
        *
        111
        C
        112
        20140528
        113
        154245
        114
        MCSTST
        115
        TRACYF
        116
        Tracy
        117
        Fry
    </estimatedisplayresponse>
</mcsresponse>
```

Could someone point out where I am going wrong? TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the text nodes are not suppressed as you intended is that you do:

```
<xsl:template match="EstimateDisplayRequest">
    <MCSResponse>
        <EstimateDisplayResponse>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="EstimateDisplayResponse" />
        </EstimateDisplayResponse>
    </MCSResponse>
</xsl:template>
```

but you don't have:

```
<xsl:template match="text()" mode="EstimateDisplayResponse" />
```

--
P.S. Couldn't this be simpler? For example, somethig along the lines of:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
   <MCSResponse>
        <EstimateDisplayResponse>
            <xsl:for-each select="EstimateDisplayRequest/facXML/faRecord">
                <xsl:value-of select="recordCode" />
                <FromStatus>
                    <xsl:value-of select="item[itemMapCode='110']/itemValue" />
                </FromStatus>
                <ToStatus>
                    <xsl:value-of select="item[itemMapCode='111']/itemValue" />
                </ToStatus>
                <!-- ... -->
            </xsl:for-each>
        </EstimateDisplayResponse>
    </MCSResponse>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The mode did the trick - and I will definitely check out your suggestion for simplifying the xsl. I have many <farecord> elements in the rest of the xml and the first item element in each one holds the key to what type of record it is. In this case, it is an Audit entry. I have other values for itemValue when itemMapCode is 1. But still, all suggestions are welcome :)